# TypeError: handlebars is not a function - Solution?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error when I run nodemon.

brings me this message - app.engine("handlebars",handlebars({defaultLayout:'main'}));
^

TypeError: handlebars is not a function
at Object. (C:\Users\yrvsc\Documents\CrudoNodeJs\app.js:8:25)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw2dX.png)

```js
const express=require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const mysql=require('mysql');
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const app=express();

app.engine("handlebars",handlebars({defaultLayout:'main'}));
app.set('view engine','handlebars');

app.get("/",function(req,res){
   res.render('index');
});

app.listen(3000,function(req,res){
   console.log('Servidor está rodando!');
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
const hbs = handlebars.create({ defaultLayout:'main' });
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

Based on npm documentation of [express-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars)
it shows you how to config in the proper way

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: Hi! I used it once and it didn't work. With your tip it ended up working. Thanks!